# Magento cron check if file exist

Tags: .htaccess, magento, cron

Hi i have some issues with dissapearing .htaccess file in magento/media catalogue.

I want to set cron to check if this file exists and if not i want to refresh/push it to that catalogue.

config.xml file

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <watchdog_htaccess>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>mypage_watchdog/Media::updateHtaccess</model>
            </run>
        </watchdog_htaccess>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

I wrote php function:

```
public function updateHtaccess(){

    $mediaCatalog = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
    $htaccess = '.htaccess';
    $file = $mediaCatalog . '/' . $htaccess;

    if ( !file_exists($file) ){
        $mediaCatalog->import($file);
    }

}
```

I use magento 1.9

What should i do to make it work?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the cron job running?  Your model should be lower case <model>mypage_watchdog/media:: by the way

Comment: Yes i ask mainly on php function - > i check if file exists and what can i do if not?

Comment: how you want to refresh/push that file to catalogue ? do you have a copy of it somewhere?

Comment: From other destiny in ftp. Is it possible?